# How can I use PHP to Parse an <any> XML Response from SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm consuming a 3rd party WSDL using PHP's SoapClient. Unfortunately the response for the call I'm trying to do is defined as:

```
<s:complexType>
 <s:sequence>
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetSearchResult_ByFieldGroupResult">
    <s:complexType mixed="true">
      <s:sequence>
        <s:any/>
       </s:sequence>
     </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
   </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Printing out the response results in a large jumbled string, like this:

```
(
    [any] => 48F3E284-D8A8-4B8E-A015-2B579D55258C0D9A0A84-9809-486B-AE69-CD12F8926E6FLodge (INCN)Incentive Concepts            13.0000Incentive Concepts3.0000SCRAPERPKLodge - Set of 2 Pan ScrapersDurable polycarbonate pan scrapers assist with clean-up duty after meals. THIS ITEM CANNOT SHIP ALONE AND MUST BE PURCHASED WITH ANY BUNDLE, CAST IRON SKILLET, OR DUTCH OVEN.http://www.replink.net/evault/0D9A0A84-9809-486B-AE69-CD12F8926E6F/48F3E284-D8A8-4B8E-A015-2B579D55258C/48F3E284-D8A8-4B8E-A015-2B579D55258C-300.jpg<_features>2 pack, includes one red and one blackMade of rigid, easy to clean polycarbonateAssorted angles get into all nooks and cranniesPacks easily for the campsiteDoes not collect food particlesDishwasher safe2D483B02-A5F2-46DC-A5D9-2ABBC808969E0D9A0A84-9809-486B-AE69-CD12F8926E6FLodge (INCN)Incentive Concepts            14.0000Incentive Concepts4.0000SCRAPERCOMBOLodge - Set of 2 ScrapersDurable Polycarbonate Pan Scrapers assist with clean-up duty when a stiff brush isn't quite enough. The grill pan scraper has two sets of teeth designed to fit any modern Lodge Grill Pan. The pan scraper has a variety of angles for cleaning a variety of cookware. THIS ITEM CANNOT SHIP ALONE AND MUST BE PURCHASED WITH ANY BUNDLE, CAST IRON SKILLET, OR DUTCH OVEN.http://www.replink.net/evault/0D9A0A84-9809-486B-AE69-CD12F8926E6F/2D483B02-A5F2-46DC-A5D9-2ABBC808969E/2D483B02-A5F2-46DC-A5D9-2ABBC808969E-300.jpg<_features>2 pack, includes one pan scraper and one grill pan scraperMade of rigid, easy to clean polycarbonatePacks easily for the campsiteDoes not collect food particlesDishwasher safeGrill pan scraper works with any current Lodge grill panPan scraper features assorted angles get into all nooks and crannies21C2C0EC-BC12-4A2C-BF6B-0296162D924992E1704F-3BBC-489B-A0A6-CFE3FA3F3CE4Nordic Ware (INCN)Incentive Concepts            14.5000Incentive Concepts4.50006500010" Spatter CoverPrevent spattering while you cook. Vents in lid prevent steam buildup. Shown with our Bacon Meat Grill; also fits dinner plates.http://www.replink.net/evault/92E1704F-3BBC-489B-A0A6-CFE3FA3F3CE4/21C2C0EC-BC12-4A2C-BF6B-0296162D9249/21C2C0EC-BC12-4A2C-BF6B-0296162D9249-300.jpg<_features>Cooking Surface: L: 10.13 in. W: 10.13 in. H: 2.13 in.Material: BPA-free and Melamine Free PlasticWeight: 0.28 lbsFits 10" dinner plates and bacon grill plate with air ventsBefore initial use and after subsequent uses, hand wash with warm, soapy water.Top-rack dishwasher safe.For microwave and storage use only.
)
```

If I use Postman to do the SOAP request it returns a defined XML response.

I was told by the rep that I need to "customize an import interface to pull that data out" but not sure how to do that and not even sure where to start Googling. Any resources or pointing out of how to go about doing this would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: That is basically undefined content. It allows to extend the XML response with elements not specified by the WSDL. You can get anything there. I've usually seen this done for services that return XML serialized records from a DB from any kind of query. Instead of building a structure to return to clients, the server developers just dump the whole thing on clients to deal with it. Before knowing how to handle it you need to know what to expect there so you can build some sort of a structure around it (something that the server developers should have done but we're probably too lazy to do)

Comment: @Bogdan I updated the OP with what it actually returns. I know what the data I'm looking for is. So I think I can figure out what field is what, but there doesn't seem to be any way to discern when one value ends and another begins. Am I out of luck here if the 3rd party dev doesn't want to define the structure on their end?

Comment: That data seems to be 3 records from a product table of some sort (https://pastebin.com/bYVXmyaH). You need to know what each column represents, what is the record separator (most likely carriage return), and the value separator (most likely tabs or fixed column length). It's like receiving a CSV file but you do not know the structure to import it in Excel. That's what you need, a structure to which you can map that records set on top of.